# Repeated types without packed = true return DecodeError: Truncated message in protobuf

Tags: python, c, protocol-buffers

From the documentation

> For historical reasons, repeated fields of basic numeric types aren't encoded 
>       as efficiently as they could be. New code should use the special option 
>       [packed=true] to get a more efficient encoding

but it seems like if I used a repeated types such as

```
repeated int
repeated float
```

when I don't specify

```
[packed=true]
```

The message from C to python always return

```
DecodeError: Truncated message
```

Is there a specific reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: There is probably a bug in your code which is corrupting the message in-transit. One common mistake is passing an encoded protobuf as `char*` without a size. Passing a string as `char*` means that the first zero-valued byte will be considered the end of the string, but protobuf objects can contain zero-valued bytes before the end. So, your message would end up truncated. Without seeing your code, though, it's hard to say if this is the problem you are having.

Comment: I see, I am also suspecting that the code base I am looking at have some bugs, I will go through the code again to see if I find anything suspicious, thanks